# SpringBoot Security + JSTL Version Conflict Error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jstl, jakarta-migration

Is there any alternative or best way to apply presentation logic in SpringBoot views?
Instead of JSTL

After 5 days of finding error,
i am getting error in my project because i am using JSTL and springSecurity together.
And there is error because of conflicting versions.

When using Security it works fine for springBoot 3.x version.
But if i want to include JSTL it works with springBoot 2.7x version.
If i use both the Security doesn't work properly.

Comment: You need a minimum of JSTL 3.0. See abovelinked duplicate for installation instructions and in depth explanation.